# Steps per epoch doesn't behave correctly with tensorflow tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.data.dataset

I am having a problem using the `steps_per_epoch` parameter in `model.fit`. Up to my knowledge, the steps_per_epoch is used to log metrics, like a loss function, after a number of iterations, i.e., after feeding a number of batches to the model. Consequently, while training, we're able to see the loss after few iterations, instead of having to wait until the end of the epoch for the loss to be displayed. Consequently, to be, if I'm having a small data, then my model will learn a pattern just from few epochs. Consequently, I am interested to see the behavior of the model after n iterations.

First, please note that I have tensorflow version 2.3.0

Here is the data preprocessing logic (this is customized for time series data).

```
window_size = 42
batch_size  = 32
forecast_period = 3

def _sub_to_batch(sub):
    return sub.batch(window_size, drop_remainder=True)

def _return_input_output(tensor):
    _input  = tensor[:, :-forecast_period, :]
    _output = tensor[:, forecast_period:, :]
    return _input, _output

def _reshape_tensor(tensor):
    tensor = tf.expand_dims(tensor, axis=-1)
    tensor = tf.transpose(tensor, [1, 0, 2])
    return tensor

# total elements after unbatch(): 3813
train_ts_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_ts)\
                            .window(window_size, shift=1)\
                            .flat_map(_sub_to_batch)\
                            .map(_reshape_tensor)\
                            .unbatch().shuffle(buffer_size=500).batch(batch_size)\
                            .map(_return_input_output)

valid_ts_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(valid_ts)\
                            .window(window_size, shift=1)\
                            .flat_map(_sub_to_batch)\
                            .map(_reshape_tensor)\
                            .unbatch().shuffle(buffer_size=500).batch(batch_size)\
                            .map(_return_input_output)


for i, (x, y) in enumerate(train_ts_dataset):
    print(i, x.numpy().shape, y.numpy().shape)
```

And the output:

```
0 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
1 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
2 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
3 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
4 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
5 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
6 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
7 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
8 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
9 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
10 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
11 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
12 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
13 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
14 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
15 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
16 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
17 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
18 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
19 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
20 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
21 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
22 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
23 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
24 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
25 (32, 39, 1) (32, 39, 1)
26 (29, 39, 1) (29, 39, 1)
```

Therefore, I can tell that my dataset contains a total of 27 batches, each batch contains 29-32 elements of shape (32, 39, 1), (32, 39, 1).

As for the model:

```
import datetime

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

time_steps = x_train.shape[1]

def _custom_mae(y_pred, y_true):
    _y_pred = y_pred[-forecast_period:, :]
    _y_true = y_true[-forecast_period:, :]
    mae = tf.losses.MAE(_y_true, _y_pred)
    return mae

model = k.models.Sequential([
#     k.layers.Bidirectional(k.layers.LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(None, 1)),
    k.layers.Conv1D(256, 16, strides=1, padding='same', input_shape=(None, 1)),
    k.layers.Conv1D(128, 16, strides=1, padding='same'),
    k.layers.TimeDistributed(k.layers.Dense(1))
])

_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H-%M-%S")
_log_dir = os.path.join(".", "logs", "fit4", _datetime)

tensorboard_cb = k.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=_log_dir)

model.compile(loss="mae", optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01), metrics=[_custom_mae])

# , validation_data=valid_ts_dataset
history = model.fit(train_ts_dataset, steps_per_epoch=12, epochs=1, callbacks=[tensorboard_cb])
```

I got the following output:

So, I can tell that I had 12 virtual epochs within a real epoch.

[image]

However, after looking into `history.history` I got the following:

[image]

However, I'm expecting to see a list of 12 values for each the `loss` and the `_custom_mae`

**Finally, I would love to see the results in tensorboard.**

Please let me know what I am missing and how to tackle my problem.

Thanks in advance for the support!

Comment: I added tensorboard to my answer tell me if it helps

Answer (score 0):

From the keras doc

> steps_per_epoch: Integer or None. Total number of steps (batches of samples) before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next epoch. When training with input tensors such as TensorFlow data tensors, the default None is equal to the number of samples in your dataset divided by the batch size, or 1 if that cannot be determined. If x is a tf.data dataset, and 'steps_per_epoch' is None, the epoch will run until the input dataset is exhausted. When passing an infinitely repeating dataset, you must specify the steps_per_epoch argument. This argument is not supported with array inputs.

So I think what you're looking is callbacks, in the same way as the tensorbard_cb, I wrote for you a callback that will be run between every batch, you can find the full possibility of callbacks here https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/#a-basic-example

```
logdir = "logs/scalars/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir + "/metrics")
file_writer.set_as_default()

class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        print("For batch {}, _custom_mae is {:7.2f}.".format(batch, logs["_custom_mae"]))
        tf.summary.scalar('_custom_mae rate', data=logs["_custom_mae", step=epoch)
```

which can be used like that

```
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)


history = model.fit(train_ts_dataset,
 steps_per_epoch=12,
 epochs=1,
 callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, CustomCallback()])
```

Then run tensorboard

```
%tensorboard --logdir logs/scalars
```

more info [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/scalars_and_keras#logging_custom_scalars)